# Printing a Graphic Object VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a module that generates fill out a System.Drawing.Graphics object.

I then try to print it with a event on my main form but the print preview comes out blank.

This is my print page

```
   Private Sub MyPrintDocument_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles MyPrintDocument.PrintPage
        Dim MyGraphic As Graphics

        MyPrintDocument.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top = 200
        MyPrintDocument.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left = 100
        MyPrintDocument.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right = 100
        MyPrintDocument.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom = 75

        MyGraphic = MyGrpahicPage
End Sub
```

`MyGrpahicPage` is the public graphics object my module fill out.

Comment: You are not drawing anything.  Use, say, e.Graphics.DrawLine() to see something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have to print to the Graphics object provided by the event argument, not another one that you may have hanging around.  In other words, you need to draw on `e.Graphics`.  The help page for [PrintPageEventArgs.Graphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printpageeventargs.graphics.aspx) shows how this is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the way.
1. step: you must create thy MyGraphics in your form:
... Form declaration  ...
    Private GrBitmap As Bitmap
    Private GrGraphics As Graphics
    Dimm Withevents pd as new PrintDocument 'The withevents is important!
...
2. step: Anywhere (ig, in the formload sub, or in a buttonclick sub) :
       GrBitmap = New Bitmap(Width, Height)
       GrGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(GrBitmap)
...
(the Width and the Height values you must calculate by the content of the graphics)
3. step:
Complete the GrGraphics with any .DrawString, .DrawLine, etc. methods
4. step:
Create a sub of Printdocument:

Private Sub pd_PrintPage(sender As Object, ev As PrintPageEventArgs) Handles pd.PrintPage

```
    ev.Graphics.DrawImage(Me.GrBitmap, New Point(0, 0))
```

End Sub